# How to distort an image using Distort() method?

Tags: c#, graphics

I tried this code:

```
Bitmap newBmp = QuadDistort.Distort(source, topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight);
```

QuadDistort doesn't exist in the current context. Which class is this object in? Is there a better way to distort an image?

Comment: That's not part of the framework, it looks like you copied that line from [here](http://www.vcskicks.com/image-distortion.php) and didn't download the library with it. Or didn't reference the assembly from your source. Or didn't add the using clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are referring to:
http://code.google.com/p/ebrsoftmbplugins/source/browse/CoverArt/Code/3D/QuadDistort.cs?r=3f47a728b6e7bdf7a0e796f4f57c0d9c52219aff

You just need to add this class (or dll) to your project.